# Hair renders from regions outside vertex group

Tags: particles

I have a vertex group and hair renders outside the region.  I can reverse it by the double arrow and that works - no hair inside my vertex group.  I have no modifiers applied. How can I only get hair from my vertex group?

[image]

Comment: When you assign vertices to a vertex group you assign them by *Weight*, i.e. how much this vertex affects/is affected by whatever is using it.  Weights are interpolated along edges between vertices, which creates a smooth look, which is what you are experiencing (go into weight paint mode to see what I mean).  Unfortunately I don't know if it is possible to not do this.  I have a couple Mickey-Mousey ideas but I'll see if anyone has anything more elegant before posting.

Comment: You are on the right track; the heat map extends beyond vertices and edges.  Unfortunately, my 2.76 doesn't look like the manual for weights...

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by "2.76 doesn't look like the manual for weights"?

Comment: Version 2.76 doesn't look like online manual - different weights panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with many things in life, I do not know the answer. But I do know how to cheat.

In edit mode, subdivide the faces you want hairy. Create a one-face-wide border between the hairy area and the rest of the surface. Assign your weight to the inside faces, and make sure your border faces are blue. Looking at the mesh in weight paint mode will show you if the hairs need a broader border area...

I am not sure this is right, but it mostly works....

[image]

Comment: Great... and a note: When you are working on some kinds of objects -- animals, human head, etc. --  a hair cap also assures exact coverage... see: http://bensimonds.com/2011/02/17/hair-in-blender/  at the bottom of page. Not always a good solution for animation, but a really precise way to control coverages.