# Grass grows through the floor of my building

Tags: particles, hair

I'm trying to make grass and a house, but, the grass just grows through the floor. How can I remove the grass where it is touching the building.
[image: there is supposed to be a floor in the house but the grass just goes over it]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing you are using a hair particle system for your grass. If so: Use a vertex group and weight painting to control placement of grass (and its length, if you want; see : [Increase Intensity of Vertex Group](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63774/increase-intensity-of-vertex-group) ).

In edit mode, subdivide the mesh on which the grass is placed, select the mesh squares outside of the house and assign them to a vertex group. You can control the placement even more if you then switch to weight paint mode.

[image]

This use the vertex group control in your particle system to place the grass only in the vert'ed areas.

[image]

You'll end up with something like this, but prettier):

[image]

Also related, particularly about finer placement of hairs:

[How do I make hair particles appear on top of the emitter and not through it?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57576/how-do-i-make-hair-particles-appear-on-top-of-the-emitter-and-not-through-it/57600#57600)

[Hair renders from regions outside vertex group](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42367/hair-renders-from-regions-outside-vertex-group/42428#42428)

Answer (score 3):

Another way would be to use texture to affect hair particles density.
If painting that texture directly, make sure to unwrap the mesh, paint the texture (white - where the grass should be, black - where should not, you can invert colors in UV/Image Editor):

[image: screenshot of texture setup]

Then  assign it in the textures panel of the particle system settings (as it should be hair type). Make sure to set *Mapping* to UV map you created, uncheck *Time* in the *Influence* rollout and check *Length* under Hair section:

[image: screenshot of the particle system setup]